# Rails with Cells and Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells

I'm having trouble accessing the cookies object in my cell views via `helper`. My code looks like this:

```
#cell
helper SessionsHelper

#cell view
signed_in?

#sessions helper
signed_in?
    cookies.sth
end
```

I'm getting the error: `undefined local variable or method`cookies'`.

How do I make cookies visible there?

Alternatively, I'd like to pass Helper as an object collaborator to my cell, because this helper contains a lot of useful methods. Is doing `SessionHelper.new` the correct way to do that?

```
<%= render_cell :my_cell, :display, session_helper: SessionsHelper.new %>
```

I now see that `SessionsHelper` is in fact a module, so I cannot invoke the `new()` method. What should I do with undefined cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I always define `signed_in?` in `ApplicationController`. (There `cookies` *is* available) And then do:

```
helper_method :signed_in?
```

to make it available as a helper method.

As for your second question: `session_helper: SessionsHelper.new` is not necessary. *All* methods from *all* helpers are available *all* views.